# Arrays and generic classes that extends another class: Possible in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

### I have an address book and two types of Contacts:

- Persons
- Organizations

Both of them extends **Contact** class.

---

I want a method of a class to **return an array of contacts**.

```
public method(args...): Array<Contact> {...}
```

Nice, but what if i have that method to **do something with some properties of the Contacts** inside the array?

```
public method(args...): Array<Contact> {
  contacts :Array<Contact> = getContactsFromSomewhere();
  contacts.forEach( contact => {
    if(typeof contact === "Person"){ //persons and organizations are different, they have different atrributes
      //Here i modify some Person attributes
    }
    else{
      //Here i modify some Organization attributes
  });
  return contacts;
```

This feels cumbersome, difficult to read. **Why not something like this?**

```
public method(args...): Array<T extends Contact> {
  contacts :Array<T extends Contact> = getContactsFromSomewhere();
  contacts.forEach( contact => {
    contact.doSomething() //abstract method implemented in both classes its own way.
  });
  return contacts;
```

Impossible, i **can't do this**

```
Array<T extends Contact>
```

This **error** is thrown by VSCode:

> [ts] Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s)

### Is possible working with an array that uses a generic class that extends another class in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know the answer to your problem based on your question, as you wrote:

> contact.doSomething() //abstract method implemented in both classes
>   its own way

You can use the same way you already have, without the "cumbersome" part.

For example, if you want to filter out the contacts that start with a string then just have a `startsWith` method for `Contact` and implement it in all subclasses, then when you iterate the contacts this method is always available and there's no need to check the specific type:

```
public startsWith(prefix: string): Array<Contact> {
    return getContactsFromSomewhere().filter(contact => contact.startsWith(prefix));
}
```

Since you probably have the contact name in the base `Contact` class, there's no need for it to be abstract but just for the sake of the example.

In cases in which you need to treat the contacts differently you have 3 options:

(1) Check the type like you did:

```
public sizeGreaterThan(min: number): Array<Contact> {
    return getContactsFromSomewhere().filter(contact => {
        if (contact instanceof Person) {
            return min === 1;
        } else {
            return (contact as Organization).size() >= min;
        }
    });
}
```

(2) Have different contact "getters" which filter the contacts array:

```
function getOrganizations(contacts: Contact[]) {
    return contacs.filter(contact => contact instanceof Organization);
}

public sizeGreaterThan(min: number): Array<Contact> {
    return getOrganizations(getContactsFromSomewhere()).filter(organization => organization.size() >= min);
}
```

(3) Have different data structures for the different types, and then do the same as in (2).

Another two comments on your code:

- Inside your method use `var` or `let` for the `contacts` variable, otherwise you're polluting the global namespace
- Use `instanceof` instead of `typeof` because:

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22object%22%0Aconsole.log(a%20instanceof%20A)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true))

```
class A {}

let a = new A();
console.log(typeof a); // "object"
console.log(a instanceof A); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare a generic signature like that, in your example typescript thinks that you want to *use* the generic signature of Array, and **T extends Contact** is not a type, it's a generic signature.

You can do it like this:

```
public method<T extends Contact>(...args): Array<T>
{
    var contacts: Array<T> = getContactsFromSomewhere();
    contacts.forEach( contact => {
        contact.doSomething() //abstract method implemented in both classes its own way.
    });
    return contacts;
}
```